# Remove specific line in a csv file defined by the string in selected item in listbox - winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, csv

I have a csv file populated as follows:

```
NAME,GAMES PLAYED, GAMES WON, GAMES LOST, AVG SCORE
PLAYER1,0,0,0,0
PLAYER2,0,0,0,0
PLAYER3,0,0,0,0
PLAYER4,0,0,0,0
PLAYER5,0,0,0,0
```

The listbox "lsbSelectName" is populated listing PLAYER1, PLAYER2 etc. What I am trying to achieve is to select a name from the listbox and when the delete button is pressed i want it to read the lines from the csv file and if a line contains the player name selected it deletes that entire line. I've tried for 2 days now but seem to be getting myself in a muddle. Here's the code so far:

```
private void btnDeletePlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string playerStats = "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\Work\\Visual Studio\\dbstats\\dbstats\\bin\\Debug\\playerStats.csv";
        string lineToDelete = lsbSelectName.ToString();

        if (File.Exists(playerStats))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"playerStats.csv");

            if (lines.Contains(lineToDelete))
            {
                lines.Skip(50);                    
            }
            else
            {                    
                MessageBox.Show("That name does not exist, Try again");
            }
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(playerStats, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(lines);
                MessageBox.Show("Player: " + lineToDelete + "Has been deleted");
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("playerStats.csv does not exist, Check Filepath");
        }
        gamesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
        lbNewPlayer.Visible = false;
        tbNewPlayerName.Visible = false;
        btnAddNewPlayer.Visible = false;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

I did little changes in path, getting lineToDelete string:

1. Read text
2. Enumerate all lines
3. Split by ',' character
4. If first string is equal to player name then skip it.

   ```
       string playerStats = "D:\\playerStats.csv";
       string lineToDelete = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

       if (File.Exists(playerStats))
       {
           string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(playerStats);

           using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(playerStats, false))
           {
               foreach (var line in lines)
               {
                   string[] parts = line.Split(',');
                   if (parts[0] != lineToDelete)
                   {
                       sw.WriteLine(line);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("Player: " + lineToDelete + "Has been deleted");
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("playerStats.csv does not exist, Check Filepath");
       }
   ```